# How can I create a Python method that finds the UUID of a CloudFormation stack with Boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

We currently use:

```
cloudformation = environment+"-"+role
qa = QAWS()
qa.initialize(environ)
events = qa.cfn.describe_stack_events(StackName=sn)
"Some interesting stuff:
event["Timestamp"]
event["ResourceStatus"]
event["ResourceType"]
event["LogicalResourceId"]
if exists = event["ResourceStatusReason"]
"""
return events["StackEvents"]
```

This works for most our Cloudformation stacks, which are:

- test-vpn
- test-app

But not for some of our stacks that have UUID's:

- test-rds-CRC25DFADXZR

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently done something similar with a "unique-id" that was inside the names of the cloudformation stacks, what you could in theory do is just remove the role etc. and search for 'test' that way you will only get stacks that are made like 'test-vpn' 'test-activedirectory' etc.

```
import boto3
import re
from sys import argv

"""
profile = AWS CLI profile you want to use, a.k.a what account you want to run this in.
region = Self explanatory, generally eu-west-1/2 etc.
unique_id = Your unique id for the CF stacks, i.e test, ppe or prod

Example usage: python delete_stacks.py test eu-west-1 test

"""
_, profile, region, unique_id  = argv

session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
client = session.client('cloudformation', region_name=region)

response = client.describe_stacks().get('Stacks',[])
stacks = []
for r in response:
    ((stacks.append(r['StackName']) if unique_id in r['StackName'] else None))

print("These are the stacks that were found")
print(stacks)


for s in stacks:
    events = client.describe_stack_events(StackName=s)
    print(events)
```

This was written in python3, i'm not sure what python version you are using to do the development so you might need to tweak if using python2.